# starting jar file exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jar, pom.xml

I packed my programm using Maven package, when im trying to satrt Jar file it gives me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.16.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.16.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.16.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I tried to delete compile and change it to runtime. Thats not helps

Comment: This can happen when you have namespace conflicts... you should only need selenium-java...  remove the other dependencies.